# Ubuntu 14.04 dell e5440 no sound

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I have ubuntu 14.04 on my dell e5440.
Every time I start ubuntu there is no sound at all unless I plug in headphones.
The only way that the speakers work is if I suspend my laptop and wake it up.

I've tried reinstalling pulseaudio and restarting alsa,
checked that it is not muted in alsamixer and setting the default sound card to the proper one.

Any ideas?
Should I install the 12.04 driver pack?

Comment: Do any drivers show up when you open the additional drivers option in the settings? You can open the tab by running: software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4

Comment: Just the Nvidia graphic card

Comment: Are you able to try it from a live USB or CD to check if sound works there. Before you do that. go to your sound settings then output device tab. what are the options for output device or devices

Comment: in the sound settings the only option is Speakers (built in audio) regardless if the sound is working or not